# Why is Ruby telling me present? is false when a value is there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, activesupport, is-empty

I thought

```
arg.present?
```

was the truth and the light in order to check whether a string was empty or nil, however I'm noticing a confusing case.  If my string is:

```
arg = "\t"
```

I get a wrong result:

```
2.4.0 :003 > arg = "\t"
 => "\t"
2.4.0 :004 > arg.present?
 => false
```

What is a more foolproof way to check whether my string argument is empty or nil?  Sure, I could write `arg.empty? || arg.nil?` but I was looking for a more concise way.

Comment: Will `to_s.empty?` work?

Answer (score 9):

So `#present?` it the opposite of [`#blank?`](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank%3F), and `#blank?` is defined as "An object is blank if it’s false, empty, or a whitespace string."

"\t" is a whitespace string (a tab), and therefore it is `#blank?`, and it is not `#present?`

Note that "\t" is only interpreted as a tab because of the way the string has been constructed.

```
2.2.5 :001 > "\t".present?
 => false 
2.2.5 :002 > '\t'.present?
 => true
```

Comment: "Note that "\t" is only interpreted as a tab because of the way the string has been constructed." "has been constructed"? Escaped characters are ignored with a single-quote and honored with double-quotes: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading and perhaps playing with the examples in [Active Support's Core documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#blank-questionmark-and-present-questionmark).

This might help explain:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'

empty_str = ''
tab = "\t"
period = '.'

empty_str.empty? # => true
empty_str.present? # => false
empty_str.blank? # => true
```

An empty string is `empty?`, it has no value (or content) so there's nothing to be `present?`, and it's `blank?` because it's `empty?`.

```
tab.empty? # => false
tab.present? # => false
tab.blank? # => true
```

`tab` isn't `empty?` because it has content, but it's whitespace so it's not `present?` and it's `blank?`.

```
period.empty? # => false
period.present? # => true
period.blank? # => false
```

`period` isn't `empty?` or `blank?` because it's not whitespace, but it is `present?`.